# Move Sprite in direction of rotation

Tags: unity, sprites

I have the following code.

```
void Update () {

        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical")!=0)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(-transform.right);
        }

        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")>0)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed*-1);
        }
    }
```

This obviously moves my sprite in an asteroids fashion. What I really want is the sprite to track the direction it is facing (ie like a car) so as you rotate the sprite it continues its movement in the direction it is facing rather than the initial direction the force was applied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple thruster like behaviour when rotating sprite](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26597/simple-thruster-like-behaviour-when-rotating-sprite)

Comment: Nope. It is the opposite of that. I already have a thruster style movement.

Comment: Apologies, I'm tired and I completely misread your question. [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37623/5404) might help you though (it's about moving towards the mouse, but a similar concept). There's also some linked questions on the right of that question that may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotate the transform object, rotate the velocity vector by the same amount.

Comment: Looks like this is what I need, However I can't seem to find a simple velocity rotate example that works.....

Comment: @coolblue2000: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/46770/rotate-a-vector3-direction.html